# How do I retrieve the service principal password after creation using the azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I create a service principal using the `az` cli tool like such

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <name>
```

I get all the information printed

```
{
  "appId": "...",
  "displayName": "...",
  "name": "...",
  "password": "...",
  "tenant": "..."
}
```

That is all good, but how do I retrieve that information at a later point? Using

```
az ad sp list --display-name <name>
```

does give me almost what I want, but I'm missing the `password`. How do I retrieve the password without resetting it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I retrieve the password without reseting it?

In short, **impossible**.

When you use commond [`az ad sp create-for-rbac`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#create-a-service-principal) to create a service principal, output for a service principal with password authentication includes the password key. **Make sure you copy this value - it can't be retrieved.** If you forget the password, [reset the service principal credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#6-reset-credentials).

> As of Azure CLI 2.0.68, the `--password` parameter to create a service principal with a user-defined password is no longer supported to prevent the accidental use of weak passwords.

When use `az ad sp show --id xxxxx` to get the details of a service principal. (autogenerated) The passwordCredentials is always null, so, the password could only retrieve when created.

[image]

Comment: Same as users, an API allowing retrieval of password would imply it is being stored in a format that allows getting it back to clear text. This would go against good security practices of using a one-way hashing function.

Comment: @juunas, password is probably the wrong thing I'm looking for. On GCP I can download the credentials for a service account and then use that file to authenticate with. To get that file I still need to have permissions to do so.

Comment: Sounds like GCP might be generating credentials at the time? `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name <name>` is kinda equivalent to that.

Comment: This answer is technically wrong/incomplete. You can re-run the `az ad sp create-for-rbac` command and if the SP already exists it patches it. So we can theoretically retrieve the password using the --query password. One thing to note dote, is that the command resets the password.

Answer (score 6):

To get a password you can run this command instead

```sh
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $NAME --query password -o tsv
```

And If you would like to get objectId or appId

You could run this command

```sh
# objectId
az ad sp list --display-name $NAME --query [].objectId -o tsv

# appId
az ad sp list --display-name $NAME --query [].appId -o tsv
```

Comment: This doesn't get the password already used to create the sp, this reset its password and return the new one.

Comment: @PhoneixS: I think that was missing from the answer, but under some circumstances is might be what the user is looking for. The alternative is to create a new SP with roles, etc. which might not be feasible.